# Quartz scheduler executes multiple times concurrently on a scheduled time

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, weblogic, quartz-scheduler

I have used quartz scheduler in my spring boot application . I am using java programmatic scheduling not a spring based annotated one. Here's the snippet

```
 Scheduler scheduler = 
 StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(ExPJob.class) .build();
 CronScheduleBuilder cronSchedule = 
 cronSchedule (mycronExpression)
    .withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing();
```

I am shutting down this as bellow

```
@PreDestroy
Public void shutdownSch(){
 Scheduler scheduler = 
 StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
 scheduler.shutdown();
}
```

Whats my problem ?
  --  if I do a re/deployment for my app.war, In Weblogic thread pool does not get killed, and after scheduler starts,
It creates another thread pool it seems.

For Example : if I schedule a cron Job  at 4 PM lot of jobs are firing at the same time. I have tried to find the PID in Linux box I'm not getting any regd this zombie threads.

What are the solutions tried ? --
    I am able to kill jobs successfully via jobkeys 
    scheduler.deletejob(jobKey) .

So why issue still persists ?
 -- I have done a series of deployments without the above mentioned job killing code before.
So, I suspect those jobs/threads are already running inside JVM. I tried a weblogic restart via console through MWare folks. But still no luck. Kindly pour your thoughts.

Comment: It's not clear the problem you're looking for help with. Is it that multiple jobs are fired, or that the shutdown code isn't executed, or some WL deployment related issue, or are you asking how to manage jobs in WL?

Comment: Problem is multiple jobs fired at a scheduled time.

Comment: Solved this via JVM re-start and added Thread.Sleep(1000) before sched.shutdown(false);